# Multiple models accessing same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-datamapper

I am new to Datamapper and Ruby on Rails. I have an en existing model A, now I want to create another version of model A, v2_A. The difference between A and V2_A is that I have changed a few belongs_to from A to v2_A by changing :required => true to :required => false like following.

```
class A
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :p1, ...
  ...
  belongs_to :b, :required =>true
 end

 class v2_A
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :p1, ...
  ...
  belongs_to :b, :required =>false
 end
```

So basically all column names in resulting tables will be same. Whenever I am doing `rake db:autoupgrade` a new table v2_A is being created which is not desired. I am asking is it possible both of the models access the same table A i.e. I don't want v2_A to create another table just because of that.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about DataMapper::Resource

But i guess  in your model you can write
self.table_name = "name_of_your_table"

In both of the model.

Comment: where should I write it? I am asking because I have put it within the class A, like self.table_name = 'a', a is the name of the existing table. Then when I do rake db:autoupgrade it is telling that undefined method "table_name".

Comment: You need to write
self.table_name = "name_of_your_table" in your model
and to skip the migration file. remove that migration file if you don't need it.

Comment: In datamapper, there is no such migration file.